# MySQL Where Date is greater than today

Tags: mysql

I try to get every record from my MySQL database which is greater than today.

```
SELECT `contract_to`
     , CURDATE() 
  FROM `contacts` 
 WHERE `contract_to` > 'CURDATE()'

Actual Result I expected
contract_to  |  CURDATE()
2021-03-27   |  2019-03-30
```

but I got the following

```
contract_to  |  CURDATE()
2019-03-20   |  2019-03-30
2021-03-27   |  2019-03-30
```

[image]

Comment: SELECT contract_to, CURDATE() FROM contacts WHERE contract_to < CURDATE()

Comment: Are the single quotes around curdate() at the end of the query intentional. Try removing them... So your condition is contract_to > CURDATE()

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

SELECT contract_to FROM contacts WHERE contract_to > CURDATE();

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT contract_to, CURDATE() FROM contacts WHERE PERIOD_SUB(contract_to,CURDATE())>0
```

it should do the trick